# Applying negative margins on cards to achieve masonry effect

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to achieve a masonry effect that looks something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the cards in the middle of this layout are `60px` above the surrounding cards.

To achieve this, I've tried to add `-60px margin` to the center cards, but it doesn't work.

I can't see a way in which I can use something like `:nth-child(2n+1)` to make this work also, as the 5th card, for example, does not fit that css rule.

Is this the best way to about it or is this achievable via css grid, without negative margins?

```css
.section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.card{
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.card__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 467px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* have tried below */

.card:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.section__card--2{
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--1">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close with your attempt. The best thing to do is to properly separate the rows into CSS rows (since you already defined the rule of 3 images per row with the `col-md-4`).

So, in your HTML, for every 3 images, you can separate them into rows with a custom class (for example: `section__row`). And in your style, you just add:

```
.section__row > .section__card:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

Final code:

```css
.section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.card{
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.card__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 467px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.section__row > .section__card:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="row section__row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--1">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row section__row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aplly `margin-top` property to `.section__card` class.

```css
.section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.card {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.card__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 467px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* have tried below */

.section__card:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top:-60px;
}

.section__card:nth-child(5) {
  margin-top:-60px;
}

.section__card--2 {
  margin-top: -60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--1">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--2">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 section__card section__card--6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url( https://i.picsum.photos/id/219/200/300.jpg?hmac=RGnJfbO2380zLCFSj2tm_q0vW0wtw67d0fhWHX2IoDk ); "></div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```